# CSS Flexbox - Same column width at colspan

Tags: css, flexbox

I have two containers with 2 and 3 boxes insinde. The space between the boxes is fix.

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e9dnxm3w/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.container {
    display: flex;

    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

div.container > div {
    flex: 1;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 50%;

    background-color: blue;
}

div.container > div:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}

div.container > div.two {
    flex: 2;
}
```

My problem is that i want the column to have exactly the same width (resp. the spaces at the same position). How can I tell the Flexbox it should ignore the margin-left or calculate it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

so, flex-basis doesn't include margins (but includes padding)

therefore, for getting your grid displaying correctly, you need to manually add the "missing 10px margin" to the flex-basis value:

```
div.one
{
    /* ... */
    margin-left:10px;
    flex-basis:100px;
}

div.two
{
    /* ... */
    flex-basis:calc(200px + 10px); /* add the margin of the missing box */
}

div.three
{
    /* ... */
    flex-basis:calc(300px + 20px); /* add the margin of the two missing boxes */
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/tndgvkfq/

Comment: Thank you for your great answer! But how can I understand the flex-basis? I don't have a "size", because it's dynamic (relative to the number of elements).

Comment: flex-basis is the natural dimension of the flex-item before it gets stretched or shrinked. in your case you can even use a flex-basis of one single pixel, it would work anyway